# Why don’t we consider $g$ for a body along one dimension?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

When a body is moving along a straight line path , we consider its acceleration in the formula.Then why don’t we also consider the force of gravity on that body.It will also decrease its velocity right?

Does it get included in the formula somehow or why do we take it as zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the formula:
$$
x(t) = x_0 + vt+\frac{1}{2}at^2
$$
Where $x_0$ is the initial displacement, $v$ is the velocity and $a$ the net acceleration.

This formula does actually include gravity. Specifically, $a$ is the net acceleration, coming from all forces (gravity frequently being one of them). However, if you are moving on a flat surface then the force of gravity will usually be cancelled by a normal force. You should draw a free-body diagram with all forces included to determine what the value and direction of $a$ should be.

---

Let me give two examples:

If you have a body in free fall (e.g. you throw a rock from a cliff), then the only force (neglecting air resistance) is gravity, $F=-mg$. In this case, $a=-g$ and gravity is what gives you the acceleration.

If, on the other hand, you are considering e.g. a car accelerating along a straight road, then the forces acting are gravity, the normal force perpendicular to the car, and the force from the road on the tires due to the acceleration of the car. The normal force compensates the force of gravity, so the net acceleration $a$ is exclusively along the direction of the road.

Comment: By your last “ Then normal force compensates ...”.Do you mean to say g =Normal force.Then how is g=0?

Comment: $g$ is not $0$ in this situation, but Newton's second law states that the sum of all forces is equal to $ma$. You have one force from gravity $F_g = -mg$ and a compensating normal force $F_N = +mg$, so their sum is zero, and gravity does not contribute to the acceleration of the object.

Comment: Thank you.Do you mean to say that because of conventions of motion , You took -mg and +mg?@G.Lang

Comment: It is the third law of Newton,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion

Answer (score 0):

When considering the effect of gravity on a relatively small system near the surface of the earth, we generally choose a coordinate system in which, g, acts only in the y direction (in one dimension).  This cannot be done when working with orbits.